# Connection Framework with .Net assembly connector

Tags: search

I am working on replacing our protocol handler with a Connection Framework component, so that SharePoint will crawl our data source.  I think I understand the big picture, but I'm missing a lot of the details.  I've read the documentation starting at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556429%28office.14%29.aspx.  I currently have a working BDC assembly; I know it works because I can make an external content type list from it.

I am currently stuck on [step three](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554911%28office.14%29.aspx): "Use Microsoft SharePoint Designer to discover the DLL and create a model".  I don't see where to do this at all.  Under "Data Sources"?  Can I use my BDC assembly for this, or do I have to create another assembly?

Comment: @bmm6o: That's now fixed. Thanks for your question and welcome to SharePoint Overflow! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a really good tutorial [here](http://toddbaginski.com/blog/how-to-create-a-searchable-sharepoint-2010-bdc-net-assembly-connector-which-reads-from-a-flat-file/) and [here](http://toddbaginski.com/blog/how-to-register-an-external-content-type-with-the-sharepoint-search-service/).